# Trigonometric functions on a unit circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, circles

I'm trying to digitalize this image with Overleaf. It represents some trigonometric functions (*sin, cos, tan, cot*) within a unit circle.
It seems very difficult to do so. In fact, I have been seeking help on posts related with pgfplots and similar packages, but anything hasn't helped yet.
I'll attach the image for a more visual approach.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Visual description of the problem]

Comment: Maybe try to post what you have done so far and where you are stuck. Unit circle visualisation is quite common on tex.SX so maybe also look for other posts, like for example this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356618/how-can-i-draw-a-chord-of-a-unit-circle

Comment: You could start with the tutorial in the PGF-Tikz manual https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tutorial/

Comment: The code in the example Raoul mentions has a few things that are not recommended (`minimal` class, `\def` instead of `\newcommand`, and `\tikzstyle` instead of `\tikzset{foo/.style={..}}`), but as he says it's in the manual: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf look at chapter 2,

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an option that will adjust the picture to whichever angle you choose:
[image]

The command `\trigfuns[<scale>]{<angle>}{<label>}` will produce the desired image. The optional argument is a scale factor for the entire figure. Default is 1, which will produce a circle of radius 1cm.

The angle is given in degrees. Smaller than 20 or larger than 60 and the labels start to get crunched.

In the image above, the second diagram was produced with `\trigfuns[2]{40}{x}`, which is a 40° angle, labeled with an `x`, and the third diagram uses `\trigfuns[2]{50}{50^{\circ}}`.

The label is parsed in math mode. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\trigfuns}[3][1]% #1 is scale factor (default=1), #2 is angle
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1, semithick, every node/.style={circle, inner sep=.1mm, font=\scriptsize}]
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];
        \draw (0,0) -- (#2:{max(sec(#2),cosec(#2))});
        \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- ({cot(#2)},1)node [label={[above, midway]$\theta$}] {};
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,{tan(#2)})node [label={[right, midway]$w$}] {};
        \draw ({cos(#2)},0) -- ({cos(#2)},{sin(#2)})node [label={[left,midway]$s$}] {} 
            -- (0, {sin(#2)})node [label={[above,midway]$t$}] {};
        \node at ({.5*cos(#2)},{.5*sin(#2)}) [label=#2+90:$1$] {}; 
        \draw (0:.3) arc (0:#2:.3)node [label={[yshift=.3mm,right,midway]$#3$}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\trigfuns[2]{30}{\frac{\pi}{6}}\hspace{-3mm}\trigfuns[2]{40}{x}\qquad\trigfuns[2]{50}{50^{\circ}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're  working with Overleaf, alternatives to TikZ (PSTricks, Metapost, Asymptote) are available. Here a possibility using Metapost, if you consider to give it an opportunity:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}
\newcommand{\nicecircle}[2]{%
\begin{mpost}[name=circle]%
vardef nicecircle(expr unit, Angle) = 
    image(
    %Circle
    path C; C := fullcircle scaled (2*unit);
    pair P[];
    %Radius
    P[1] := dir(Angle)*unit;
    %Some other points
    P[2] := P[1] scaled (1/cosd(Angle));
    P[3] := P[1] scaled (1/sind(Angle));
    P[4] := (xpart P[1], 0);
    P[5] := (0, ypart P[1]);
    draw C;
    draw origin -- P[3] -- (up*unit) -- origin;
    draw origin -- P[2] -- (right*unit) -- origin;
    draw P[1] -- P[4];
    draw P[1] -- P[5];
    label.rt(\btex $s$ etex, 1/2[P[1], P[4]]);
    label.top(\btex $t$ etex, 1/2[P[1], P[5]]);
    label.top(\btex $\theta$ etex, 1/2[up*unit, P[3]]);
    label.rt(\btex $w$ etex, 1/2[right*unit, P[2]]);
    label(\btex $x$ etex, 1/5*unit*dir(Angle/2));
    label.top(\btex 1 etex, .5[origin, P[1]]);
    %Metapost circles are divided in 8 parts, so we divide our angle by 45
    draw subpath (0,Angle/45) of fullcircle scaled (1/5*unit);
    )
enddef;
draw nicecircle(\mpdim{#1}, #2)  withpen currentpen;
\end{mpost}%
\usempost{circle}%
}
\begin{document}
\nicecircle{8em}{30}%Try another angle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've been testing a little, this is my result. If anyone wants to improve it, he/she's welcome to do so.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=30pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
 % TIKZ STYLES
 \tikzstyle{important line}=[very thick]
 \tikzstyle{information text}=[rounded corners,fill=red!10,inner sep=1ex]
 \def\costhirty{0.8660256}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
my angle/.style={draw, <->, angle eccentricity=1.3, angle radius=4.5mm}
                        ]
% COLORS
  \colorlet{sincolor}{red}
  \colorlet{tancolor}{orange!80!black}
  \colorlet{coscolor}{blue}
  \colorlet{cotcolor}{yellow}
  \colorlet{omegacolor}{green}
  \colorlet{epsiloncolor}{purple}
% coordinate axis
\draw[<->] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
\draw[<->] (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5);
% circle
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
% coordinates
\coordinate[pin= 300:{$( 1,0)$}] (A)  at (2,0);
\coordinate[pin=150:{$(0, 1)$}] (B)  at (0,2);
\coordinate (E)  at (1,0);
\coordinate[pin=100:{$(2,2\sqrt{3})$}] (F)  at (2, 3.46410161514);
\coordinate[pin=360:{$\tan x$}] (G)  at (2, 1.26410161514);
\coordinate[pin=270:{$\cos x$}] (H) at (0.55, 0);
\coordinate[pin=280:{$\sin x$}] (I) at (1, 1);
\coordinate (J) at (1.15470053838, 2);
\coordinate[pin=90:{$\cot x$}] (K) at (0.8, 2);
%
\coordinate                 (M) at (60:2);
\coordinate                 (O) at ( 0:0);

% angles
\draw[thick, sincolor]    (M) -- (E);
\draw[thick, coscolor]    (O) -- (E);
\draw[thick]              (O) -- (F);
\draw[thick, tancolor]    (A) -- (F);
\draw[thick, cotcolor]    (B) -- (J);
\pic[my angle, "$t$"]      {angle = E--O--M};
\newline
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can define `F` at `(2,{2*tan(60)})` and, using the `calc` TikZ library,  you can define `G` at  `($(A)!.5!(F)$)`. The TikZ math engine knows `cos()`, `sin()`, `tan()`, `cot()`...